# Show news on homepage AW_Blog

Tags: magento

I installed the AW_Blog extension, however I can't seem to find anything on my frontend (it's a custom build theme I'm working on). I would like to receive all posts (or last x posts) to manually put them in a slider.

How do I grab all those posts in my .phtml layout file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the 10 latest blog posts :

```
<?php

$_sql = "SELECT * FROM `aw_blog` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `aw_blog`.`post_id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10";

$_connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

foreach ($_connection->fetchAll($_sql) as $_post) {

$_post_date = date("m/d/y", strtotime($_post['created_time']));
$_post_content = strip_tags($_post['post_content']);
$_post_url_slug = $_post['identifier'];

}

?>
```